# Extracting all pixel values in raster?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am using QGIS and I have a raster from which I would like to extract all the pixel values and if possible their corresponding coordinates.

I am able to use the identify feature option to point to a location on the raster to get the individual raster value; but, I would like to do this for all points without having to click all of them.

Comment: If it's a single band raster translate to XYZ format, this will give you a file of all the X,Y and cell values in text, but such a file can be unwieldy. What sort of raster is it?

Comment: It is an elevation raster that I obtained by performing DSM (raster)-DEM (raster) . I will try what you said, I am quite new to this. Thanks for your input.

Comment: What is the ultimate objective? It seems like may need to do some sampling across your raster. What is the purpose of obtaining all the pixel values? Would you prefer this summarized in a histogram?

Comment: @MichaelStimson thanks for your advise, I was able to get the values from Qgis using the Translate option. Though the text file created was really big, I was able to split it using a software.

Comment: @Aaron, I have a two GeoTiff (DSM and DEM) files one containing the bare earth returns (DEM) and the other containing the returns afters the plants have been planted into the soil (DSM). We are trying to track the growth plants on regular intervals, so I was trying to calculate the height by obtaining the pixel values at each coordinate in the raster (DSM - DEM). I am not sure what is the best way to summarize this huge data. Let me know if you have some ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Text XYZ is probably the *worst* raster format for size, even more bloated than Esri ASCII, but some packages (for example AutoCAD) will only use gridded XYZ. If you have a sub-area in mind you can use -srcwin (offset, rows and columns) or -projwin (extent of the sub-area in georeference coordinates) with GDAL_Translate to create smaller files.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I do have a specific area where I want to extract the measurements from and I was using the clipper function in Qgis to extract only a part of the raster that I needed. I am trying to figure out GDAL as I am new to this. Thanks for the references to the commands.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run "[Raster Pixels to Points](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#raster-pixels-to-points)" from [Processing Toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html); This will create a point on each raster pixel containing the corresponding raster-value
2. Run "[Add geometry attributes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#add-geometry-attributes)" from [Processing Toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html) on the newly genereated point layer; This will add coordinates to your new points

Of course there are other methods (e.g. field calculator) and tools (e.g. polygonize raster pixels) as well. But on the given question, I assume this is the most straight forward and simple one.